# Can't seem to submit to Google forms through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-forms

I am trying to send a Google form through the backend; my node.js instance. When I call the request, I get a response of the Google form telling me I need to get all inputs before submitting, but I have all of them.

I used this tool to attempt to extract the code and submit it: https://stefano.brilli.me/google-forms-html-exporter/

Here's the submission code:

```
presetValues = {fvv: "1", fbzx: "7516357733560172960", pageHistory: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14", emailAddress: 'test@email.co}
values = Object.assign({entry.123456: 'test1', entry.128738: 'test2'}, presetValues);

request.post('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<someID>/formResponse', finalValues, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    res.send(error)
    console.error(error)
    return
  }
  console.log(response)
})
```

I tried to submit directly through the form and took a look at the request body, and here's what I found was sent:

```
emailAddress: valid@test.co
entry.482058093: Completely Agree
entry.1744297141: Completely Agree
entry.254955372: Completely Agree
entry.947249041: Completely Agree
entry.1454952975: Completely Agree
entry.3576454: Completely Agree
entry.1246226991: Completely Agree
entry.1190333749: Completely Agree
entry.1613073769: Completely Agree
entry.1314940116: Completely Agree
entry.1953426485: Completely Agree
entry.1934717828: Completely Agree
entry.596033500: Completely Agree
entry.1143227505: Completely Agree
entry.1446585381: Completely Agree
entry.632378461: Completely Agree
entry.392810795: Completely Agree
fvv: 1
draftResponse: [[[null,1685503023,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1114836796,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1357049422,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,86605751,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,472640154,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,578340154,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1342145939,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,908476553,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1767728649,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,261135357,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,955881343,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,644828648,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1389259807,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1119338533,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1062429863,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,785038336,["1"]
,0]
,[null,516860473,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,567444201,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,482251296,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,498646145,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1560601161,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1444586702,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,922754460,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1557835370,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,467854058,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1589546710,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2108902598,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,281144796,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1530873848,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1424024691,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1731945609,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,907193508,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1153672983,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,813826338,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,580562563,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1831284314,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1993591785,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2006331742,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1827982714,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,993541708,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1391636956,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,91447117,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,114054349,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1479669058,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,169007299,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1674987636,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,781409566,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1715842899,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2122555380,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1839860132,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1798162602,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,534974595,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1915445764,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1620257977,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,147518034,["6"]
,0]
,[null,1081230217,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1830529504,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,898930382,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1192389256,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,151544055,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,349843311,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1121996014,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1257519461,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2041168852,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1448317082,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,822017211,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2070207179,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1294073322,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1350554776,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,331473110,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1872389749,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1316304979,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1757255400,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1067906573,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,470696499,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1626751662,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1276689933,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1113634309,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1155614358,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1958637973,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,470332824,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,392453027,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1589198700,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1949725356,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,849004808,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2092761804,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,161553396,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,586309661,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,936612705,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1122630561,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1928824068,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,548688753,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1889668025,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,432775722,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,443111614,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1021968621,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1203098592,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2144723307,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1915333401,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1894339866,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,645054929,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,206646349,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1650858765,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,82078653,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1371169995,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,271214876,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,410917678,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1192455003,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1412652069,["a bird"]
,0]
,[null,1661631785,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,578250942,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,33974948,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1087544379,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,610072221,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1196285049,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,399911317,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1339798463,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1139777018,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1253745912,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1018082058,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,618305883,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1673555985,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,69524582,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,751997319,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1688009496,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1878671812,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1628966265,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1131585981,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,865622826,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,839910403,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,329075391,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,797122277,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,51198863,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,814847401,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1139951685,["6"]
,0]
,[null,1292307698,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,249345051,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1347230989,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1823033486,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1997754411,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1943812633,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,2068211302,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1848471308,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,908441447,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1003990001,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,718684127,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,392810795,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,947249041,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1454952975,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1143227505,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1246226991,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1613073769,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,632378461,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1934717828,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1744297141,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,3576454,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,482058093,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1314940116,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,254955372,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1190333749,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,596033500,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1953426485,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
,[null,1446585381,["Completely Agree"]
,0]
]
,null,"-6523179267803174631",null,null,null,"valid@test.co",1]
pageHistory: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
fbzx: -6523179267803174631
```

Here are the request headers:

```
:authority: docs.google.com
:method: POST
:path: /forms/d/e/<formID>/formResponse
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 12593
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: S=spreadsheet_forms=<someID>; some more values...
origin: https://docs.google.com
referer: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<formID>/formResponse
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
x-chrome-connected: id=115715404765572375416,mode=0,enable_account_consistency=false,consistency_enabled_by_default=false
x-client-data: CLK1yQEIk7bJAQijtskBCMS2yQEIqZ3KAQioo8oBCLGnygEI4qjKAQjxqcoBCJatygEIxK3KAQiersoB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to submit through a get request instead of a post request.